# how to set a parameter in icCube reporting that is based on other parameters?

Tags: iccube-reporting

I have a server function (MDX++) months(value M, value H).

The icCube dashboard contains two events, attached to two filters (LOVs): @{selM} and @{selH}.

How can I assign the result of the function months(@{selM}, @{selH} to a new event called @{selPeriod} that is updated each time one of the LOVs changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, such event could be generated by the cusom mdx filter that based on the manual query. You can hide somehow this filter from the result UI as it will be used only in the automatic mode.

```
Filter1 -> generates @{selM}
Filter2 -> generates @{selH}
Filter3 -> hidden, generates @{selPeriod}
```

For the Filter3 you need to switch the data configuration to MDX and put the following request:

```
WITH
MEMBER ic3Name AS months(@{selM}, @{selH})  // event caption(your function)
MEMBER ic3UName AS months(@{selM}, @{selH}) // event value(your function)
MEMBER ic3PName AS NULL
MEMBER ic3Measure AS 0
MEMBER ic3IsSelected AS true // true to throw the event automatically
MEMBER ic3FilterName as [Measures].[ic3Name]
MEMBER ic3Key as 0
SELECT
{[Measures].[ic3Name],[Measures].[ic3UName],[Measures].[ic3PName],[Measures].[ic3Measure],[Measures].[ic3IsSelected],[Measures].[ic3FilterName],[Measures].[ic3Key]} ON 0,
TopCount([Calendar].[Year], 1) on 1 // any non empty level, to have 1 row in the response
FROM [Sales] // any cube
```

Comment: I had to add to change it into:
MEMBER ic3Name AS months(@{selM}, @{selH}).name
MEMBER ic3UName AS months(@{selM}, @{selH}).key

But it works! Thank you,